# Orders don't display on customer panel after migrating server

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, customer-account

After migrating server, the order of historical stopped appearing in the client panel, appears only in the backend.

This only occurs with registered customers before migration.

When these customers (registered before the migration) makes a purchase, after the payment, the order disappears off the customer panel.

I have already checked the config file, and all of the statuses are set 1 to frontend view, so what could it be?

Comment: Do you still have access to the old server? Do you have any modules that work with customer orders?

Comment: I havent access to the old server, I think the em_deleteorder is the only module that work with customer orders. I also work with onestepcheckout. The question is, why this trouble occour only with the old customers?

Comment: My personal experience with em_deleteorder is that it causes problems. It doesn't remove all the information so it could actually lead to the type of problem you are describing. I would try a test environment create and delete some orders with that module and see if you can reproduce. Use the same version of magento and delete order.